# Adding custom indicator to cufflink

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, quantitative-finance, candlestick-chart

I'm adding some pre-built indicators to cufflink/plotly with this code:

```
qf = cf.QuantFig(df, title="Apple's stock price in 2021", name='AAPL')
qf.add_sma([10, 50], width=2, color=['blue', 'red'])
qf.add_rsi(periods=14, color='green')
qf.add_bollinger_bands(periods=20, boll_std=2 ,colors=['orange','grey'], fill=True)
qf.add_macd()
qf.iplot(layout=layout_cf)
```

Is there any way to add a `List` or `Pandas Series` as a custom indicator? if this option is not available is there any way to add a function in the source code that would allow this?

Comment: What is the numerical value of your preferred list or series? Are you referring to a unique indicator? Since this graph is a time series graph, it would need to be a data frame that contains both time series data and numbers to be added.

Comment: @r-beginners that's not a problem, since the indicator will be calculated from the ohlc data, I can create a data frame that has both values of indicator and time series. the problem is I don't know how to make cufflink show it.